# Errors Using Nested Select MySQL Statements

Tags: mysql

I am currently experimenting with using nested select statements but my subqueries are generating `NULL` values. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT filmid,datetime,title,description,
       (
          SELECT name 
          FROM fec_client 
          WHERE filmid = 'fec_film.filmid'
       ),
       (
          SELECT rating_motivation 
          FROM fec_rating_report 
          WHERE filmid = 'fec_film.filmid'
       ) 
FROM fec_film 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the quotes, otherwise you are not comparing to the values in the SQL but to strings

```
SELECT filmid, datetime, title, description, 
    ( SELECT name FROM fec_client WHERE filmid = fec_film.filmid ) AS name,
    ( SELECT rating_motivation FROM fec_rating_report WHERE filmid = fec_film.filmid ) AS rating   
FROM fec_film ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

p.s. you can also name those columns using the 'AS' keyword